# How to do voice recognition "in streaming"

Tags: ruby, voice-recognition

I want to do an application with voice recognition.

For now, I record a file and, when it's done, I send it to google speech with the file created. I want to do something more "live". I don't want to have the text when I speak. Something like this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDX-RVCmfWU but without google chrome.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should check out http://voce.sourceforge.net/ 
or http://www.simon-listens.org/